# Installed TPM, how to use BitLocker without USB key?

Tags: disk-encryption, tpm, bitlocker

I have a Windows 10 computer with 3 hard drives:

1. Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB (SSD, system drive where Windows 10 is installed, not encrypted yet)
2. First 3 TB HDD already protected by BitLocker
3. Second 3 TB HDD already protected by BitLocker

Whenever I boot into Windows, I need to type in long passwords to unlock the second and third drives. It's annoying.

So I was excited to finally install this [ASRock TPM2-S TPM Nuvoton NPCT650](https://smile.amazon.com/ASRock-TPM2-S-Module-Motherboard-V2-0/dp/B06XPR5943/ref=smi_www_rco2_go_smi_4368549507?_encoding=UTF8&dchild=1&ie=UTF8&keywords=tpm%202.0&language=en_US&linkCode=sl1&linkId=fc1a8e1f1d22fe9e8a3521811594e417&qid=1604270317&rnid=172282&s=pc&sr=1-4&tag=rycwa-20) Trusted Platform Module onto my Z170 Pro4 motherboard (which is running firmware 7.50) today because my understanding was that I would then be able use BitLocker on my system drive too and won't need to keep entering long passwords for each other drive on each boot into Windows.

I do *not* want to use a USB key. I just want my main Windows password to automatically decrypt all 3 drives when I log into Windows.

The BIOS successfully recognized the installation of the TPM:

[image]

And Windows 10 did too:

[image]

### Here is my problem. When I click "Turn on BitLocker" for my C drive, it forces me to set up a USB key, which I don't want to do:

[image]

[image]

I have already tried clearing the TPM:

[image]

I also tried changing settings in Windows Local Group Policy Editor, but then when I clicked "Turn on BitLocker" for my C drive, I got the error: "The Group Policy settings for BitLocker startup options are in conflict and cannot be applied. Contact your system administrator for more information." (With other settings, I got: “The startup options on this PC are configured incorrectly. Contact your system administrator for more information.”)

What am I doing wrong? **How can I enable BitLocker on my C drive without setting up a USB key?**

---

### Here are some other screens, which may be helpful:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the option "Prepare the TPM" grayed out after clearing the TPM? If yes than TPM is not clearing. You need to clear the TPM from the BIOS. Once it is cleared click on "Prepare the TPM".

Comment: Just a side note: TPM isn't required for Bitlocker on the boot drive. You can use a boot-time password (Bitlocker calls it a "PIN" but it doesn't have to be numerical) for encrypting the system drive with BitLocker, which can then automatically decrypt the other drives as well. You will still need to log in to Windows after booting, though. TPM-only is more convenient, sure, but TPM+PIN (or TPM+startup key) is more secure. You need to use `gpedit` and configure the Bitlocker settings for this, or use the command-line tools; search online if you want to try it.

Comment: @CBHacking Thanks for that idea!

Comment: "I just want my main Windows password to automatically decrypt all 3 drives when I log into Windows" I think you misunderstood how Bitlocker works. The Windows login password is never used to protect or unlock Bitlocker drives.

Comment: @Robert It's true that drives can be encrypted via BitLocker but never prompt the user for the key (and instead, the drives are immediately usable by the logged-in Windows user), right? So what I mean is that the gate is essentially the Windows password, is it not?

Comment: @Ryan in that situation, the non-system drives are usable _as soon as the system drive is unlocked_, whether or not any user has logged in. On a machine with no non-user services and only one user account this distinction wouldn't matter, but Windows typically runs a lot of services in non-user service accounts. Possibly you don't care about what they can access, though.

Comment: @CBHacking Interesting. So if I use BitLocker in the normal most convenient mode, the only protection that BitLocker offers is against theft of the drive *without* also stealing the TPM module. If someone steals the whole PC (which is the most likely case) and therefore now owns the drive, motherboard, TPM chip, etc, then BitLocker has not benefitted me at all. It seems like only if I use the mode where I'd subject myself to the inconvenience of typing in a pre-boot PIN would I get that extra security. Correct? Thanks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker#Encryption_modes

Comment: Bitlocker still benefits users in TPM-only mode, at least against attackers who aren't sophisticated enough to use a cold-boot or other direct memory access attack to pull the key out of RAM, and can't bypass the normal OS access control. The TPM doesn't just store the key, it _seals_ it such that the key isn't available if the boot process is modified (a different operating system, or modified system firmware). Thus, Bitlocker will only decrypt the drive if the OS boots normally, at which point the attacker either needs to extract the key from RAM or bypass the OS security (user login, etc.)

Comment: With that said, combined modes such as TPM-and-PIN or TPM-and-startup key are definitely more secure, protecting against both theft of the whole system (drive, TPM, firmware, and all) without the PIN/key, and protecting against offline brute-forcing the PIN/password on a stolen drive.

Comment: Oh ok, great. Thank you for all of this extra helpful info, @CBHacking!

Answer (score 0):

The operating system needs to claim the TPM. That can be done by clearing it first. After that, the boot process gets attested and the Bitlocker key can be unlocked using TPM. Please note that anytime you change something in the BIOS or the startup sequence or add additional hard drives or USB thumb drives, the unlock key needs to be entered again.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've already tried clearing the TPM via the link shown in the first image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5GL1.png. Are you saying I should try again? I know of 2 other ways to clear the TPM, the 2nd being the one shown at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLxoJ.png and the 3rd being in the BIOS, but I read that Windows requires *not* to use the BIOS method. Why do you think clearing it didn't work the first time? Do you know specifically what I should do? Thank you so much!

Comment: Depending on your boot method, you might need to switch to TPM v1.2 compatibility. TPM 2.0 needs, as far as I remember, secure boot enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried Clear TPM multiple times using the first 2 approaches. Then I tried setting the BIOS "Device Select" to TPM 1.2 instead of "auto". Now neither the BIOS nor Windows detects that I have a TPM at all. So I'm returning it. I can't believe I wasted 8+ hours on this. Thank you so much for your ideas, though. It was nice to feel like someone was here trying with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't initialize the TPM. Once you clear the TPM you need to click on "Prepare the TPM" option under tpm.msc which  should be enabled instead of greyed out. If it is greyed out after clearing the TPM from tpm.msc then you probably need to clear the TPM from BIOS settings.

After finishing with "Prepare the TPM" process you should be able to see more options on right pane of tpm.msc.

Prepare the TPM functionality actually helps you to take the ownership of TPM hardware installed. After you have ownership, you can use it for encrypting the hard disk with bitlocker.

Below link will be helpful:

[Initialize TPM](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1103910-initializing-trusted-platform-module-tpm-for-encryption-management-for-microsoft-bitlocker-install)

[Troubleshoot TPM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/initialize-and-configure-ownership-of-the-tpm)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Although I don't remember ever seeing the exact phrase "Prepare the TPM" and have never seen it in anyone's screenshots or instructions, I do see in my notes and own screenshots from 2020 that I followed these steps: I rebooted into the BIOS menu and in Advanced > “Trusted Computing” changed HashPolicy from Sha-1 to Sha-2 and in Security changed Intel Platform Trust Technology from Disabled to Enabled. Then tpm.msc said “The TPM maintenance task is still running. Please wait a few […]” After waiting and refreshing, it said “The TPM is ready for use.” (Seems prepared.)

Comment: In your own screenshot of tpm.msc, above the "clear TPM" there is a phrase "Prepare the TPM". But anyway, as per your process you were using fTPM and changing the hash policy might have cleared the TPM and given you the ownership.

Comment: Ahh, I do see that now in the screenshot. Thanks.